# Get reference to original element when dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am using HTML5 native drag and drop for dropping images into a div. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/ipojuk/1/

The problem is, once dropped the same image should not be dropped again. How to prevent this from happening? For this purpose i have set a `data-inplan` attribute in image, and i was planning to set it to `true` once an image is dropped, but i can't find an easy way to get a reference to the original image in function `dragDrop`. I thought about using an `id`, but these images are created at runtime, and generating id's will be hard for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to drop only one image per type (checking the src)

```
function dragDrop(e) {

 if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting
  }

  var $item = $(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));

  var exists = false;
  $(".divRendezvous img").each(function()
  {
    if($(this).attr("src")==$item.attr("src"))
    {
      exists = true;
      return;
    }
  });
  if(!exists)
    $item.appendTo(e.target);  
  return false;
}
```

**jsBin**: http://jsbin.com/ipojuk/12/edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you are only preventing re-dropping the cloned image. How to do the same with the original image?

Comment: So you just want to be able to drop the image once? Meaning, the div will have only ONE image in total at any given time?

Comment: Gotcha, lets check it out.